Microsoft Entra ID: How Do I Get the Authorization Code?
I have a React frontend and a .NET Core backend. I want to implement the Authorization Code Flow by retrieving the code using MSAL then passing it to my backend to get my access token. However, I'm having trouble somehow moving my configuration away from the Implicit Flow.
The documentation says to uncheck both Implicit Flow options in the Authentication section, send a request via loginRedirect() using MSAL v2.x, redirect to an /auth/callback route to handle the response promise, and upon handleRequestPromise() pass the authorization code to my backend to retrieve my access token. I've done all this, even repeating the process a couple times to cover all my bases, and using a Quickstart application to verify that the authorization code in the response still remains as undefined.
Although, I am able to sign in, the response I get gives me an access token which I presumed wouldn't be provided per my configuration. Then I saw this graphic on the Quickstart tutorial and it got me thinking, is there no way to directly retrieve the authorization code? But how I understand the graphic, there is no backend, and this is really just the Implicit Flow, no? Unless I'm understanding the Authorization Code Flow incorrectly, which I'm basing my knowledge off of this definition from the OAuth 2.0 docs.

Here's a snippet of what my response looks like without giving away too much information:

I'm open to any feedback or recommendations. Thank you for your time!

The diagram describes the Authorization Code Flow for a Front-End/SPA-only application.
The Implicit Flow skips steps 2 and 3 of the diagram (the Authorization Code round trip): the AIP (here Microsoft Identity Platform) directly sends the access token when it redirects to the Client application.
If you have a .NET Core Back-End, you should use it with MSAL.NET and an Authorization Code Flow for Web appplication.
Unfortunately, many diagrams confuse the Front and Back End sides of the Client application, and even for the browser ("user agent") part, it may not be very clear whether you need your Front-End code or not.
Referring to the diagram here, you need your (React) Front-End only for steps 1 (landing) and 2 (redirection to AIP).
Step 4 goes through your visitor's browser, but you should not need any Front-End code there: normally you configure a Back-End route as the redirect configured route to receive the browser request, which includes the Authorization Code. Then you use it in your Back-End with MSAL to get the Access token.
With this scheme, your Front-End code does not need MSAL, it is used only initially to send the visitor to the AIP. It also never sees the Authorization Code: sounds like this is the confusing part from your question.
